# I keep getting "Could not find or load main class" error despite using a Manifest file for an executable jar

Tags: java, jar, manifest, executable, executable-jar

Basically I was learning the compilation process of an executable jar file. So, for that purpose, inside a directory `src\com\mftest`, I have a file named `Test.java`, with the following contents.

```
package com.mftest;

public class Test
{    
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {    
        System.out.println("Hello from Test!");
    }
}
```

Now, from the main folder (one containing the `src` folder), where I also have the folder `bin`, I type `javac -d bin src\com\mftest\Test.java`. This creates the file `bin\com\mftest\Test.class`.

Then, from within the folder `bin\com\mftest`, I create a file `Manifest.txt` with the following contents. Note that here there are two lines, with the 2nd line being blank.

```
Main-Class: com.mftest.Test
```

From within the `bin\com\mftest` folder, I now type `jar cmvf Manifest.txt Test.jar  *.class` to create the file `bin\com\mftest\Test.jar`. I expected that file to be executable, but when I try to run it by typing `java -jar Test.jar`, I get the following error.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.mftest.Test
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mftest.Test
```

Any idea, what mistake am I doing here?

Comment: I have read all those answers, and that is how I came to know that I have to add this manifest file. I did that, but still getting the error.

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't work out. The very first answer there turns in **length** about how source paths and class paths must come together. And that com/mftest is part of the class name, and thus that the hierarchies must match up.

Comment: @GhostCat. Don't worry, I got it working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From within the bin\com\mftest folder, I now type jar cmvf Manifest.txt Test.jar  *.class to create the file bin\com\mftest\Test.jar

I think I see your problem.

If you run `jar tvf Test.jar` I expect that you will see that path for the `Test.class` file within the JAR file is `"/Test.class"`.  It should be `"/com/mftest/Test.class"`.

Your mistake was to change directory to `bin\com\mftest`.  You should have created the JAR file from within the `bin` directory to get the pathnames in the JAR correct.

Note that the manifest file you include in the JAR could be anywhere.   You just need to provide the correct (file system) path for it in the `jar` command.

Comment: You mean the Manifest.txt file should be in the bin directory, and I should type jar cmvf Manifest.txt Test.jar  com\mftest\\*.class, from there?

Comment: Beautiful man, this indeed solved the problem!